# How to keep counter of number of responses in dialog flow

Tags: dialogflow-es, counter

In Dialog flow, i want to take action after user has asked 3 questions. I don't know how to keep the counter of the responses. There is no integration here.

Comment: Please show use some code of what you already have tried.

Comment: I did not know how to go about it. So did not try.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way is to setup a [fulfillment webhook](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-overview) and configure each of your Intents to call this webhook. As part of the webhook, you would have it track and update a counter as part of a [context parameter](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/contexts-overview).

Libraries such as [multivocal](https://multivocal.info/) keep track of counters for each Intent and each Action you may set using this method, for example.

Comment: Good luck. If an answer has helped, accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated.